# Unexpected token showing up for custom ServiceAccount

Tags: kubernetes

I have set up a custom ServiceAccount with a ClisterRole binding. I can see the account and it's ca.crt, namespace and token.

Definition:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-app
  name: my-app-svcaccount
  namespace: my-app-ns
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: my-app-svcaccount
  namespace: my-app-ns
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: my-app-svcaccount
  namespace: my-app-ns
```

In my pod spec I have specified the serviceAccountName and expect it to be mounted into the pod. When I go into the pod, I see the /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ folder as expected.

Definition within deployment pod spec:

```
  serviceAccountName: my-app-svcaccount
```

However, the token in that folder is not the one from my serviceAccountName, nor of any other secret in my namespace. I'm pulling my hair as to what could be the reason for this. Where can this token be coming from and how can I find out where the incorrect token is coming from?

What I can see is that the mounted volume name does not refer to the ServiceAccount name, but rather to kube-api-access-... which is unknown to me where it's coming from.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide respective yaml manifests and commands output for better understanding.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @confusedgenius I have added the specifications.

Comment: Thank you .. please check automountServiceAccountToken is set to false in sa or pod

Comment: updating  pods yaml , sa yaml & clusterrole yamls in question will be useful .

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Unfortunately, the issue was completely unrelated to my yaml files, and was caused by a proxy configuration from within the pod. I would never have found this out, but the problem had occurred with someone else before. I was completely thrown off by the contents of the token.. Nonetheless, thanks for your help.